# Microsoft Search Server Express - how to move all the databases?

Tags: sql-server, search

I have just installed the excellent Search Server Express 2008 onto one of our servers.

As a default all the databases created are put into locations on the c: drive.

Does anyone know where all the databases are located and how they can be safely moved.

Answer (score 1):

The data files will be located within a subdirectory of the detault SQL Server Folder so

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\

[See How to: Install SQL Server 2008 (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)

In order to move your databases data files the most straightforward method would be the [Detach/Attach Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx)

As always, please ensure that you either perform or already posses a backup of your database data prior to carrying out such administrative tasks..

Comment: This is not correct. The databases are not located here and a simple detach/attach does not take into account the search/sharepoint services that are running.